# How to find the Webtable header values using UFT

Tags: header

How to find the web table header values using UFT. When row value is zero. I need to compare the header_names like so expected table name in dynamic

Comment: use code format only for code

Comment: i was tried to avoid that.but i could not able to post question that's why i am used code format